# Islamic calendar has appeared after Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade

Tags: 20.04

I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 today and it seems that I now have an Islamic calendar in the top bar of my main window. I'm most confused as I didn't ask for it, and don't seem to be able to remove it. alt+ right click doesn't give any option to remove it and I'll be honest, I don't want it!

Screenshot of calendar and 'about' screen from right click of top bar icon:

[image: screenshot of calendar and 'about' screen from right click of top bar icon]

I'm also having other issues after upgrading, but those can wait for now!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The calendar shown on your screenshot is created by `hijra-applet`.

To remove it use commands below:

```
sudo apt-get remove hijra-applet
sudo apt-get autoremove
```